# How to split string on '/' delimiter but prevent splitting when '/ '  occurs just after ' \ '

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split string data using Python which is delimited by the '/' character. The problem is that the string could have multiple occurrence of the '/' character but I want to split it only using '/' and not using '\/'

For example, I am trying to split the string '1\/2/CD' into '1\/2' and 'CD'

Comment: The title asks something entirely different than the question...

Comment: Yes it does, and I had to delete my answer.

Comment: Apologize for the confusing title.

Comment: @stressed_geek: So edit your question's title.

Comment: Do you have to account for occurrences of `\\` right before a `/`, like splitting `counter\\/example` into `counter\\` and `example`? In that case you have to start parsing from the start of the string, and there are no solutions with negative lookbacks (because you'd have to account for 1, 2, ... sets of `\\`).

Comment: I'd try findall with something like `/(?:[^\\/]|\\.)*/` instead -- match a sequence of either bare or backslashed characters, where the bare characters aren't slashes or backslashes.

Comment: @John Machlin: Done. Hope this title makes more sense. Please let me know if it is still inappropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind assertion in the regexp:

```
>>> re.split(r'(?<!\\)/', r'1\/2/CD')
['1\\/2', 'CD']
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re#regular-expression-syntax):

> ```
> (?<!...)
> ```
>
> *Matches if the current position in the string is not preceded by a
>   match for `...`. This is called a
>   **negative lookbehind assertion**. Similar
>   to positive lookbehind assertions, the
>   contained pattern must only match
>   strings of some fixed length. Patterns
>   which start with negative lookbehind
>   assertions may match at the beginning
>   of the string being searched.*

This works when you have the first slice empty:

```
>>> re.split(r'(?<!\\)/', r'/CD')
['', 'CD']
```

Comment: +1 for getting it right the first time :-) You might also want to point out the `maxsplit` parameter (since that seems to be what the title is asking about)

Comment: Thanks, this works. Had tried this earlier with (?!...) as mentioned in the python docs at the following link:

http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html 

Why is there a difference in syntax between the two docs?

Comment: Got it, for some reason the HowTo here http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html just talks about negative lookahead assertion and not lookbehind.

Comment: Moreover, why do we need to escape the '\' in re.split(r'(?<!\\)/', r'/CD') even though we have defined the regex as a raw string?

Comment: @stressed_geek: Defining the string as a raw string means python won't do anything with the backslash - but it has special meaning in the regex itself - so I have to further escape it since I mean it literally withing the regex too - without raw strings I'd need four backslashes as in `'(?<!\\\\)/'`

Comment: because the backslash is still needed to escape quote, and therefore it is needed to escape the backslash. There's not really a way around this, unless the language allows you to define your own delimiters.

Comment: What if there are two escape characters? The escape character itself is escaped and then the split should be done. In a more general way: (odd number of escape characters -> don't split) (even number of escape characters -> split)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split method of the  regex object, just split on `/` which isn't following a `\` (using negative lookbehind):

```
import re
str = u'1\\/2/CD' 
re.split(r'(?<!\\)/',str)
```

Comment: The string`s `split()` method does not "accept" a regex. Rather, a regex object also has a `split()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I incorporated them in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the delimiter is always at the end of the string you can user str.rpartition:

```
>>> print u'1\/2/CD'.rpartition('/')
(u'1\\/2', u'/', u'CD')
```